# How make auto-startup menu for systemrescuecd

Tags: iso, syslinux

I looking solution to my question. I download ISO of SystemRescueCD and I know how to add some paarameters to linux line but I dont know how to make it auto running menu.

In fact I put there DEFAULT directive which highlight menu position and that last think, how to automaticlly run ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as easy job. All what you need is edit a sysrescd_head.cfg file and put DEFAULT and TIMEOUT directive. Remeber that. Timeout takes values in 1/10 of seconds so '10' is in fact (10/10 = 1) one second waiting